# "Target of jump differs in high-order 4 bits from instruction pc 0x400014"

Tags: assembly, mips

I am currently doing a MIPs assignment and I keep getting this error. I searched the error on google and all I found was another question on stackoverflow, and the answer given there really didn't help much because I still don't understand it. This is a homework assignment, so I don't think I should share my source code, but in my assignment I'm translating C code that has a main function, that calls a second function, which itself calls a third function that recursively calls itself until it returns something to the second function, and then the second function returns something to the main. When I get errors like that, where exactly should I begin looking to try to fix it?  I guess this is not the best way to ask for help since I'm not posting source code, but if ANY advice can be given, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes I read that and it makes absolutely zero sense. It doesn't tell me how I would be able to fix the problem

Comment: Without seeing the code in question it's going to be hard for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: If you read the link offered by the link you'll see that you can solve this problem by using `jr`